# sqlite updateData - statement not working

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am using SQlite as my database and am coding in Java the `newID();`, `updateTable();` & `updateData();` functions are given below

```
public void newID(){
                String sql = "select count(*) ID from CashierDetails";
                try{
                    pst= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                    int id = ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue() + 1;
                    jTextField1.setText("" + id);
                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        
public void updateTable()
            {
                String sql = "select * from CashierDetails";
                
                try{
                    
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    jTable5.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                }
                
                
            }
            
public void updateData ()
            {
             
                String sql = " update CashierDetails set " 
                        + " CashierName = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"
                        + " SecretQ = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"
                        + " Answer = '"+jTextField18.getText()+"',"
                        + " MobileNo = '"+jTextField3.getText()+"',"
                        + " Address = '"+jTextField5.getText()+"',"
                        + " Email = '"+jTextField4.getText()+"',"
                        + " Password = '"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"',"
                        + " ConfirmPass = '"+jPasswordField2.getText()+"'"
                        + " where CashierID = "+jTextField1.getText();
                
                String sql2 = "update CashierAccount set "
                        + " Username = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"
                        + " SecretQ = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"
                        + " Password = '"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"',"
                        + " ConfirmPassword = '"+jPasswordField2.getText()+"',"
                        + " Answer = '"+jTextField18.getText()+"'"
                        + " where CashierID = "+jTextField1.getText();
                
                
                try
                {
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pst.execute();
                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                    pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql2);
                    pst.execute ();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cashier Details have been updated");
                    pst.close();
                    rs.close();
                    updateTable();
                    newID();
                    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
                
        
                        
                        
                
            }
```

the function gives no errors and doesn't throw any exceptions rather it shows a dialog box saying "Cashier Details have been updated" but in the SQLite CashierDetails table the details are not updated neither in the CashierAccount table, below is the SqLite table
[The CashierDetails Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5vV7.png)
[The CashierAccount Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICtkt.png)

Now if I were to populate the table through SQLite studio (i.e. create a row and input data from SQLite Studio) than that specific row can be updated through the `updateData();` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently it turned out to be a problem with closing the prepared statement. The below code works fine and updates the list as required

```
public void updateData ()
    {
     
        String sql = " update CashierDetails set " 
                + " CashierName = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"
                + " SecretQ = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"
                + " Answer = '"+jTextField18.getText()+"',"
                + " MobileNo = '"+jTextField3.getText()+"',"
                + " Address = '"+jTextField5.getText()+"',"
                + " Email = '"+jTextField4.getText()+"',"
                + " Password = '"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"',"
                + " ConfirmPass = '"+jPasswordField2.getText()+"'"
                + " where CashierID = "+jTextField1.getText();
        
        String sql2 = "update CashierAccount set "
                + " Username = '"+jTextField2.getText()+"',"
                + " SecretQ = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"',"
                + " Password = '"+jPasswordField1.getText()+"',"
                + " ConfirmPassword = '"+jPasswordField2.getText()+"',"
                + " Answer = '"+jTextField18.getText()+"'"
                + " where CashierID = "+jTextField1.getText();
        
        
        try
        {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            pst.close();
            updateTable();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql2);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            updateTable();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cashier Details have been updated");
            
            pst.close();
            rs.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        

                
                
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call `pst.executeUpdate()` instead of `pst.execute()`

Comment: Can you share what is the final string in sql and sql2 variables after making query?